# Теги статей в одном поле

Tags: php, sql

Добрый день.
Есть таблицы Статьи, Теги и ТегиСтатей (id, idArticle, idTag).
Статья может иметь несколько тегов.  
Как получить поля НазваниеСтатьи [Статья], Теги [ТегиСтатей join Теги]?
Но прикол в том, что я бы хотел в поле теги получить не один ответ, а сразу все для данной статьи, например, [машины, техника, железо], а ещё б лучше ещё и ссылку как-то прицепить, например, при нажатии чтоб выглядело mysite.com/tag/машина.

Ну или проще говоря, как вывести данные в формате [машины, техника, железо] в одной ячейке, если они в разных строках базы данных?
Подскажите, как такое реализовать.
Спасибо.

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, чтобы оформить простой перевод строки, надо отбить два пробела перед единственным переводом строки, для разрыва абзацев надо отбить два и более перевода строки, вот так:

    простой разрыв<пробел><пробел><перевод>
    простой разрыв

    разрыв абзацев<перевод>
    <перевод> [от одного до скольки угодно раз]
    разрыв абзацев

Не надо запихивать текст в код. Текст - это не код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, a.content, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS tag_list
FROM articles AS a
LEFT JOIN relations AS r ON r.article = a.id
LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON r.tag = t.id
GROUP BY a.id;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71dce/2)

> а ещё б лучше ещё и ссылку как-то прицепить, например при нажатии что б выглядело mysite.com/tag/машина

Плохая идея просто из-за того, что генерация URL происходит на стороне БД. Но - можно:

```
SELECT
    a.id, a.title, a.content,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT('<a href="/tag/', t.slug, '">', t.name, '</a>')
        SEPARATOR ', '
    ) AS tag_list
FROM articles AS a
LEFT JOIN relations AS r ON r.article = a.id
LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON r.tag = t.id
GROUP BY a.id;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71dce/2)

Да и вообще лучше сразу их списком получать для каждой записи.

Comment: Огромное спасибо.